# Swift - changing app when banner loads. - xcode 6 GM

Tags: swift, height, uitextview, iad, xcode6

I have been working on a mainly text-based application with an Iadbanner in the bottom.

However as we all know, Iads aren't always there. So I would like to be able to dynamically update the height of my textView, so when the banner is hidden, the textView takes up the wasted space. And resize it when a banner is loaded.

Here's what I currently have for the Viewcontroller in question

```
import UIKit
import iAd

class DetailVC: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate, ADBannerViewDelegate {

//Our label for displaying var "Items/cellName"
@IBOutlet var imageViewOutlet: UIImageView!

//connect in IB connection inspector with your ADBannerView
@IBOutlet var adBannerView: ADBannerView!

//Receiving variable assigned to our mainVC var "items"
var cellName: String = ""
var imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()
var image = UIImage(named: "handcuffs.png")
var textViewText: String = ""
var textView: UITextView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 5.0, y: 238.0, width: 315.00, height: 283.00))
//height = 332 for full screen 283 for small

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    println("+--------------------+")
    println("| Detail view loaded |")
    println("+--------------------+")

    // Iad stuff
    self.adBannerView.delegate = self
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
    self.adBannerView.hidden = true //hide until ad loaded

    //Setting up the textView
    textView.text = textViewText
    textView.editable = false
    textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    textView.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 15)

    //adding textview as subview
    self.view.addSubview(textView)

    //ImageViewOutlets
    imageViewOutlet.image = image

    //Assign your string var to your navbar title
    self.title = cellName

func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    NSLog("bannerViewWillLoadAd")
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    NSLog("bannerViewDidLoadAd")
    //self.textView.removeFromSuperview()
    //textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 238.0, width: 320.00, height: 283.00))
    //self.view.addSubview(textView)
    self.adBannerView.hidden = false //now show banner as ad is loaded
}

func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    NSLog("bannerViewActionDidFinish")
    //optional resume paused app code
}

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    NSLog("bannerViewActionShouldBegin")
    //optional pause app code
    return true
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    NSLog("didFailToReceiveAdWithError")
}

//... your class implementation code
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

The commented out code in the function "bannerViewDidLoadAd" is what I thought would have fixed my issue. Sadly that function seems to never run? I'm not very familiar with Iads so hopefully someone out there can give me a hint as to how to change the height of a textView when an ad loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CanDisplayBannerAds :

> Set this to enable automatic management of banner ad display with the view controller. It's important to note that this will modify the view hierarchy of the view controller by inserting a new container view above the view controller's view. The impact is that the view controller's view property will no longer return the originally provided view, it will return the new container. To access the original view, use the originalContentView property.

So, remove this line :

```
 self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
```

Everything should work.